# VS2013 ClickOnce Installation - Application cannot be started

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-3.5, windows-7-x64

I develop small .net applications for various little tasks in my company. I work in a Windows 7 64-bit environment using Visual Studio 2013 and have developed at least a dozen without any problems. I have a new one that's working perfectly in both Debug and Release modes in VS. After I publish and try to run the ClickOnce, I get an error: "Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor." Then it quits the installation. It's strange because I ran all my other ClickOnce files for my older applications, and they're doing the exact same thing. I never had a problem with them until yesterday.

I usually publish to our server, but I tested it on my C: drive this time to make sure it wasn't a network or sharing issue. Also tried running as administrator.

I have a Windows XP virtual machine which runs the installation fine. So, I'm not sure exactly what is going on. Anyone have any idea?

Here are the details from the error:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18444
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Temp/Medline%20Invoice%20Split.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Temp\Medline Invoice Split.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [9/26/2014 9:40:03 AM] : Activation of C:\Temp\Medline Invoice Split.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [9/26/2014 9:40:03 AM] System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        - The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore(UInt32 Flags, IntPtr hToken, Guid& riid)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore..ctor(ComponentStoreType storeType, SubscriptionStore subStore)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore..ctor(String deployPath, String tempPath, ComponentStoreType storeType)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.get_CurrentUser()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Have you seen this Stackoverflow [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423386/installation-issue-while-using-click-once-deployment)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it didn't fix my issue :/