# ClickOnce Application sometimes wont start

Tags: windows, clickonce

Sometimes on some pc with windows 8 (or 7) when the user launch the icon of ClickOnce Application wont start and nothing is showed.
After a reboot will cause to fix this problem.
Someone have an answer or a solution to investigate this strange thing?

Comment: This is extremely broad, and will likely be closed soon. Maybe the application is actually still running? Maybe it crashes on startup? Maybe it's blocked by an Anti-Virus? There's probably *thousands* of reasons why you might be seeing the problem you're seeing, and you don't give any information to narrow the problem down.

Comment: For troubleshooting the problem i have logged in a file the ClickOnce process
see https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/enhanced-logging-in-clickonce-deployment/

After this i have find the problem:
Sometimes, the "dfsvc.exe" (the clickonce manger) remain in running process,
and if you found it kill em.

After this i call the clickonce application with administator permission.

Comment: See this question for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423386/installation-issue-while-using-click-once-deployment